# How to insert an element to the heap sort using struct

Tags: c, struct, heapsort

This is the question I got as an assignment. I need to insert an element to the heap and I need to build the initial heap using the following declaration.

```
typedef struct {
    int count;
    int entry[MAXLIST];
} LIST;
```

I googled it also, but as I'm not familiar with `struct` I cannot do this question. Please help me to answer it.

Comment: What heap ? max-heap ? min-heap ?
You tagged heapsort. Do you need to sort the elements in your heap ?

Comment: Rather than post links to `struct` tutorials: there are lots of them you can easily find.

Comment: Your question is not complete.
How can you insert to a heap if there are no pointers to link them ?


Rewrite your question with the whole code so we can help you.

Comment: You've enough rep  that you should know how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  If you can't create the heap with a structure, show us how you'd do it without a structure.  If you can't find create a heap at all, don't introduce red herrings into your question.

Comment: You might want to investigate 'Programming Pearls' by J Bentley, Addison-Wesley, 1986, ISBN 0-201-10331-1, Column 12 'Heaps' (or the equivalent from the second edition).

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for help, There are a lot of resources and tutorials about how to implement a heap using C.

look up in google for: *how to implement a heap data structure in C* for example, you can also check those links:

[Heap Data Structures -with C Program source code](http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/data-structures-heaps-with-c-program-source-code)

[C Program to Implement a Heap & provide Insertion & Deletion Operation](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-heap-insertion-deletion-operation/)

And try to specify which kind of heaps you mean.

As an advice, try first to learn about the principle of data structures, start with a linked list, try to implement one in C. If you get stuck, then ask a clear and specific question, and I'm sure a lot of people would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate the struct on the heap write

```
LIST* pElement = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
```

`pElement` now points to the struct or to be more precise, an area of memory that can hold the struct LIST.

When you address the individual elements in the struct you write e.g.

```
pElement->count = 0;
```

to get a bunch of structs just allocate more space by multiplying the size of the struct with some number

```
LIST* pElement = malloc(sizeof(LIST)*10); // array of 10 structs
...
pElement[5].count = 0;
```